# Showing a map is continuous in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

We have maps $F:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ on a Banach space $X$.

Let $F(u,v) = f(u+v) - f(u-v)$. The map $f$ is nonlinear and not identically zero (to avoid trivial statements), and the map $F$ is bilinear.

Suppose we know that $|F(u,v)| \leq C|u|_X|v|_X$.

Is it possible to show that $f$ is a continuous map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $u=x/2$, $v=x/2$, then after some simplifications
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\frac{1}{4}F(x,x)
$$
So $f$ is continuous as composition of continuous functions.